# How to replace the custom post slug by the category name in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, slug

I need to change the permalink struture of my custom post "product"
the default one is Domain_name.com./product/product_name
I need to change it to :
Domain_name.com./category_name/product_name
i used the plugin "Types" to create the custom post
i installed a plugin named wp-permastructure to change the permalink but 
when i add %category%/%postname%/ in the new format structure i get a 404 error.
i add the follow code to remove the product slug :

```
function gp_remove_cpt_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) 
{
     if ( 'product' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link);

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'product', 'gp_remove_cpt_slug', 10, 3 );

function gp_parse_request_trick( $query ) {

    // Only noop the main query
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    // Only noop our very specific rewrite rule match
    if ( 3!= count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // 'name' will be set if post permalinks are just post_name, otherwise the page rule will match
    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'product', 'page' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'gp_parse_request_trick' );
```

But i still get the 404 error 
have you some ideas for my problem

Comment: @ sirina you can use 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'your-slug-here'),

Comment: thx for u'r reply , width this function i can remove the slug but i still have a 404 error